# How to upload a file to weed-fs

Tags: java, distributed, weed-fs

Hi I am trying to upload a file to weed-fs using the [weed-fs java client](https://github.com/simplebread/WeedFSClient). I think I have successfully installed weed as per the instructions [of how to install weed](https://code.google.com/p/weed-fs/wiki/GettingStarted). In short I

1. start the master with the command `$./weed master`
2. then volume servers with `$./weed volume -port=9444` my app server has already occupied port 8080
3. test that everything is working by uploading a folder with the command `$./weed upload -dir="any_dir_with_small_files"

To this point all is well.
In my app I try to post `multipart/form-data` from the browser which is intercepted by a servlet that calls a class to deal with the upload.

```
    public void upload(HttpServletRequest request) throws FileUploadException, IOException {
    client = new WeedFSClient(MASTER_ADDRESS, MASTER_PORT);
    if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        FileItemIterator fileItemIterator = new ServletFileUpload().getItemIterator(request);
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        while (fileItemIterator.hasNext()) {
            FileItemStream item = fileItemIterator.next();
            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                inputStream = item.openStream();
                File file = new File(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"img/uploads/"+item.getName());
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                Streams.copy(inputStream, fos, true);
                RequestResult result = client.upload(file);
                if (result.isSuccess()) {
                    System.out.println("uploaded file with ID "+result.getFid());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this I get a lot of debug info

```
    Info:   DEBUG - Get connection for route {}->http://localhost:9444
Info:   DEBUG - Connecting to localhost:9444
Info:   DEBUG - CookieSpec selected: best-match
Info:   DEBUG - Auth cache not set in the context
Info:   DEBUG - Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Info:   DEBUG - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
Info:   DEBUG - Attempt 1 to execute request
Info:   DEBUG - Sending request: POST /2,ace132597a HTTP/1.1
Info:   DEBUG - >> "POST /2,ace132597a HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
Info:   DEBUG - >> "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
Info:   DEBUG - >> "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=TVf_3Jwe1DSTTHoUnZcyiA5KCVUFixPeItY3[\r][\n]"
Info:   DEBUG - >> "Host: localhost:9444[\r][\n]"
Info:   DEBUG - >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
Info:   DEBUG - >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.5 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
Info:   DEBUG - >> "[\r][\n]"
Info:   DEBUG - >> POST /2,ace132597a HTTP/1.1
Info:   DEBUG - >> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Info:   DEBUG - >> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=TVf_3Jwe1DSTTHoUnZcyiA5KCVUFixPeItY3
Info:   DEBUG - >> Host: localhost:9444
Info:   DEBUG - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
Info:   DEBUG - >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.5 (java 1.5)
Info:   DEBUG - >> "1088[\r][\n]"
Info:   DEBUG - >> "--TVf_3Jwe1DSTTHoUnZcyiA5KCVUFixPeItY3[\r][\n]"
Info:   DEBUG - >> "Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileBody"; filename="23.jpg"[\r][\n]"
Info:   DEBUG - >> "Content-Type: text/plain[\r][\n]"
Info:   DEBUG - >> "[\r][\n]"
Info:   DEBUG - >> "[0xff][0xd8][0xff][0xe0][0x0][0x10]JFIF[0x0][0x1][0x1][0x1][0x0]H[0x0]H[0x0][0x0][0xff][0xe1][0x16][0xf2]Exif[0x0][0x0]II*[0x0][0x8][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x17][0x0][0x0][0x1][0x3][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x90][0x6][0x0][0x0][0x1][0x1][0x3][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x1a][0x4][0x0][0x0][0x2][0x1][0x3][0x0][0x3][0x0][0x0][0x0]"[0x1][0x0][0x0][0x6][0x1][0x3][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x2][0x0][0x0][0x0][0xf][0x1][0x2][0x0][0x6][0x0][0x0][0x0]([0x1][0x0][0x0][0x10][0x1][0x2][0x0][0x15][0x0][0x0][0x0].[0x1][0x0][0x0][0x12][0x1][0x3][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x15][0x1][0x3][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x3][0x0][0x0][0x0][0x1a][0x1][0x5][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x0]D[0x1][0x0][0x0][0x1a][0x1][0x5][0x0][0x1][0x0][0x0][0x0]L[0x1][0x0][0x0][0x1b][0x1][0x5]
```

this goes on like this for like x10 the height of my screen not forgetting I have set a very tiny font size.
Can someone please tell me how this should be done. And I will also appreciate it if you can guide me to a proper guide to a java client for weed fs. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are doing it right. Just turn off the debugging message if you do not want to see them.

Comment: are you the author of weed-fs distributed file storage?

Comment: "are you the author of weed-fs distributed file storage" yes.

Comment: Hello Chris I have been using weed on my site for nearly one year now. Why did you change your username on SO? It was a bit hard to find you? I wish there was a Q&A section for your weed-fs project on github or elsewhere where new users as well as seasoned weed users (no pun intended) can interact. Do you think this is something that can be done? The issue tracker page is only useful for tracking issues and bugs but other people might have problems that are not necessarily issues.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know I can change the username. Need to create a "seaweedfs" tag. Seems I do not have permission yet.